# Force {acro} package to show the list even if there is no \ac{}

Tags: acronyms, acro

Due to my small knowledge and planning skills, I wrote a quite big document using a lot of acronyms, and after I decided to insert a List of Abbrebiations using the `acro` package.

It turns out that unless you actually have e.g. `\ac{OP}` somewhere, the abbreviation

**OP** Original Post

will not appear in the abbreviations list. Is there a way to make all the abbreviations be printed in the document, even without the proper `\ac{}` in the tex (similar to `\nocite`)?.

(Yes I know... I will do it properly in the future)

Comment: Documentations are probably the most unread texts in the world. See section "Reset or Mark as Used, Test if Acronym Has Been Used"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\acuseall
```

for fooling `acro` package into thinking that they are used.

Comment: Where do I put this in my document? And somehow I can use \acro, but not \acuseall. Which package is to include?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat this was 5 years ago, apologies, I have no recollection of this thing, I have no idea

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat I'm using the package acronym and it seems to show all by default, but can be loaded with [printonlyused] if that is desired